# How to generate code128 barcode with special character '¿'?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing application with ability to scan barcodes but i have problem with some characters which mess up everything for me. Same problem occured on android and i fixed it but i can't fix it on swift in same fashion.

I have tried multiple libraries and native ways to generate image of code128 barcode from provided String. It works on everything but special characters like '¿'. I tried everything i read after googling problem but i still could not fix it.

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(barcode: String) {
        let data = barcode.data(using: .ascii)
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") else {
            return nil
        }
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        guard let ciImage = filter.outputImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(ciImage: ciImage)
    }

}

let barcode = UIImage(barcode: "some text")
```

Everything works fine when scanning this exact barcode image from card and saving the value. It even says that ";038388¿" is type code128, but when I try to generate code128 barcode image out of it, somehow it has problem with "¿" character.

Answer (score 0):

Code128 is defined as only capable of encoding ASCII, but ASCII does not have the "¿" character.

The conversion `let data = barcode.data(using: .ascii)` fails.

I would recommend catching this early using code like

```
guard let data = barcode.data(using: .ascii) else {
   return nil
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that i need to generate a barcode. Yes ascii is a problem but how come it scans the exact same character and says that it is code128 but can't generate image from it.

Comment: What is "it"? What does "it" report when "it" scans the code? Can you update your question to show the barcode that you're expecting to see generated?

Comment: Yes, but my question was about who or what "it" is in "it scans" and "it says". Your android app? A scanner app? Again, it would be helpful to see the Code128 you're generating in your android app, just for comparison.

Comment: Okay so. My ios and android app both can scan barcodes and save barcode type and barcode text on server and then display the image generated from that text and barcode type to user. Both of them had a problem with "¿" that character when generating image from barcode text ";038388¿". However i fixed it on android and failed to fix it on ios. Scanning works fine when i try to scan my card with "¿" but generating image fails